# Are there any free and open source tools to convert JPEG/GeoTIFFs to CADRG format?

Tags: convert, software-recommendations, cadrg

I am trying to convert some JPEGs/GeoTIFFs into CADRG format. I have tried to use GDAL in QGIS to convert to RPF/ADRG but with no success. There are licensed tools like ERDAS/Global Mapper which give you the option to convert to CADRG.

Is there a Free and Open Source tool to convert to CADRG?

Answer (score 1):

GDAL should have some support for that format https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/adrg.html. I would recommend to use other formats with larger support but I guess that you have some exotic software that prefers CADRG.

Command
`gdal_translate -of ADRG 004.jpg AAAAAA01.gen` did something and created three files:

- AAAAAA01.gen
- AAAAAA01.gen.aux.xml
- AAAAAA01.IMG